# Mockito parametrize methodCall in mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyServiceTest
{
   @Mock
   private static MyRepository myRepository;
   private MyService myService;

   @BeforeEach
   void setUp()
   {
      myService = new MyService(myRepository);
   }

@ParameterizedTest
   @ArgumentsSource(TestParameter.class)
   void findAllTest(Map<String, String> allParamaters, Object methodCall) throws JsonProcessingException
   {

      Element element = Element.builder().identification("id").build();

      // how to pass different methodCall according to parametrized tests
      when(methodCall).thenReturn(List.of(element));

      var expectedResponse = myService.excute(allParamaters);

      //assert....;
   }

   private static class TestParameter implements ArgumentsProvider
   {
private static final MyRepository myRepository = mock(MyRepository.class); 
      @Override
      public Stream<? extends Arguments> provideArguments(ExtensionContext context)
      {
         return Stream.of(
                  Arguments.of(Map.of("key_1", "value_2", myRepository.findComponentByKey_1(....)),
                  Arguments.of(Map.of("key_1", "value_2", myRepository.findComponentByKey_2(....)),
         );
      }
   }
```

how to pass different methodCall according to parametrized tests to `when`. I always return the same list of elements

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Your service will always call the same method on its dependencies, it doesn't make sense to stub different method calls for different test cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the methods you want to stub always return `List<Element>` , you can use  `Supplier<List<Element>>` to represent a method call. Also use `@MethodSource` to define the parameters is easier and cleaner than `ArgumentsProvider` IMO.

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("args")
void findAllTest(Map<String, String> allParamaters, Supplier<List<Element>> methodCall) {

 when(methodCall.get()).thenReturn(List.of(element));
 var expectedResponse = myService.excute(allParamaters);

}

private static Stream<Arguments> args() {

   Supplier<List<Element>> find1 = () -> myRepository.findComponentByKey_1(...);
   Supplier<List<Element>> find2 = () -> myRepository.findComponentByKey_2(...);

   return Stream.of(
           Arguments.of(Map.of("k1", "v1"), find1),
           Arguments.of(Map.of("k2", "v2"), find2)
   );
}
```